# Determine which constructs of RDFS and OWL can be expressed using monotonic rules

Tags: rdf, owl

For example, the subclass relation is represented as c(X)→c(X) (c is a subclass of c).

Comment: reasoning of RDFS and OWL RL can be represented as rules, the rules are online already. OWL DL can't be solved by a simple rule engine, this takes more complex algorithms like tableau

Comment: The character `` is in private-use area. Did you intend to use another one?